# Ruby on Rails : How to use relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

I'm new in Ruby on Rails programming. Anyone can show me, How to use relationship, how the code in models, controller and view. thanks

Comment: Follow these Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Model, View, and Controller is quite common - do a quick google on MVC tutorials.
A great resource for learning Rails quickly is http://railsforzombies.org/

Model:
Basically a Ruby class that defines a data type. Maybe a "Student" class, with the name and id, etc. The main emphasis is on the fact that the class only represents the data - it doesn't know how to render itself, etc.

View:
The .html.erb file
Given a model, or a set of models, the view generates the appropriate html to be displayed. There will normally be a set of views for each Model - one to update, to list all, to delete, etc.

Controller:
When a page is requested, the Controller usually gets some Models from a database, and uses them in combination with a View, to produce the final html for the page.